# Excel - how to return a text in a cell when something is tyed in a different cell

Tags: excel, formula

Good day

I am trying to create a worksheet where if something is typed in to a cell then a word should appear in another cell.

Let's say for example if, in cell A1 the word "Generic" is typed, then I want the number 1 to appear in cell B2, and if the word "QSE" is typed in cell A1 then I want the number 2 to appear in cell B2.

Any suggestions?

Much appreciated

Comment: Hello Derick, and welcome to the site. You generally have much better luck here if you can show that you have already researched and tried different things.  Here is a good place to start: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a small table of inputs and outputs.

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP to reference that table and return the correct value:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,F:G,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

---

If you do not want the grid but want to "hard code" in the formula:

```
=INDEX({1,2},MATCH(A1,{"Generic","QSE"},0))
```

[image]

---

One more option if you have a subscription to Office 365 Excel:

```
=IFS(A1="Generic",1,A1="QSE",2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an ***IF*** formula in cell **B2**:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1="generic",1,IF(A1="QSE",2)))
```